# What's the difference between the two online-bridge questions?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

The following questions are currently adjacent on the front page:

[Online resources for learning/practicing bridge](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/5329/online-resources-for-learning-practicing-bridge) (3 answers)

[Is there a good casual online place to practice/learn bridge?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/3633/is-there-a-good-casual-online-place-to-practice-learn-bridge) (2 answers)

Are they dupes?  Since they both have answers, should they be merged?  Or am I missing some important difference between them, and if so what is it?

Answer (score 3):

They look like dupes to me.

The reason they are on the front page, have answers, and are not already marked as duplicates is likely due to somebody using those questions as a place to advertise their bridge related website.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Ok, that explains their adjacency.  Is one a better question than the other -- which direction should the dupe go?  Should the answers be merged?

Comment: I have voted the newer one as a duplicate of the older one.

Comment: Both answer sets look of similar quality to me, but I believe the June 3, '11 question is slightly better.